# How to use a existing SSL certificate from Windows Certificate Store for a FastAPI web service?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I developed a `FastAPI` service for which I used a self-signed certificate locally in order to communicate through `HTTPS`.

Now I'm in the stage to deploy the API to a dev server. It is a Windows server using a company certificate, stored in Windows Certificate Store (WCS).

Question: what is the best way to deploy such a API, **using a certificate from the WCS**?

Locally I used `Uvicorn` where I could pass a physical path to the certificate as:

```
uvicorn.run(..., ssl_keyfile='key.pem', ssl_certfile='cert.pem')
```

However, WCS stores its certificates in the registry, so we don't have any paths to pass.